# How to draw shapes with a future timestamp in the Tradingview api?

Tags: javascript, charts, tradingview-api

I'm trying to draw a shape (`trend_line` using the `createMultipointShape()` chart method) in a TradingView screen using the JavaScript API, that has two arbitrary date points. I am able to put shapes on the screen with timestamps that have already passed; this works without any problem.

However, when drawing a shape with a timestamp **in the future**, TradingView cuts the shape off at the current date.

For example, with points: `{time: 1567330140, price: 11500}` (2019-09-01) and `{time: 1569835740, price: 11500}` (2019-09-30) TradingView shows the following output:
[TradingView chart with line cut off at the current date; magenta dashed line is what is drawn, current date is 2019-09-16](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxPsY.png).

When I draw this shape by hand, no such restriction applies. It seems I am unable to draw ANY shape in the future, not just `trend_line`. Is there any way around this? The documentation only specifies this:

> createMultipointShape(points, options)
>
> **points**: an array of objects [{time, [price], [channel]},...]
>
> ```
>  time: unix time. The only mandatory argument.
> ```

`horizontal_ray` does work (as the line goes on forever, by definition), but it does not solve my problem of having a line between points.

Answer (score 1):

To draw shapes in the future, you must ensure that the `time` of the `point` lines up with whatever bin/interval candles are currently being printed, and have the `time` be the exact timestamp of when that future candle opens.

In your example, `1569835740 * 1000` (timestamp converted to ms) is `Mon Sep 30 2019 09:29:00` - so if we are printing 1 hour bars, the timestamp would need to be exactly `9:00:00` instead of `9:29:00`.

First get your time in ms (x1000): `1569835740000`

Knowing that 1 hour in ms is 3600000, we can find the remainder to see how much we are off:

`1569835740000 % 3600000 = 1740000`

Remove the remainder to get our good timestamp in ms, then convert back to the required TV format:

`time = (1569835740-1740000) / 1000`

You may have to adjust your remainder calculation dynamically based on the current chart interval if using multiple timeframes that are incompatible.

**Full code:**

```
let time = 1569835740

time = time * 1000

let rem = time % 3600000

time = (time - rem) / 1000

widget.chart().createMultipointShape([
            {
                time: 1567330140
                , price: 10500
            },
            {
                time: time
                , price: 10500
            }
        ], {
            shape: 'trend_line',
        })
```

**Result:**

**[image]**

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. However, it does not seem to work at my end: when I try this with a date before 'now', I end up with a graph that stops exactly there (e.g. september 16: [image](https://imgur.com/a/piAc84B)); when I try this with a future date (e.g. september 18: [image](https://imgur.com/a/oYb5YeC)) it doesn't work and the line ends at the current timestamp. I hardcoded the timestamp for this test, i.e. `.setDate(18); .setMonth(8); .setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);`, which should bypass the issue presented above, right?

Comment: Have you tried plugging in the provided code and seeing what it prints on your end?  Also what version of the charting lib are you using

Comment: I just updated to the last version of the TV lib (1.14; 2019-06-14), but no luck. I tried the exact code you provided (slightly modified; see [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/qNJa1sby)); this didn't work, so I just hardcoded the points (`[{time: 1567330140, price: 10500}, {time: 1569834000, price: 10500}]`) but this also truncates the line on all intervals. Changing the remainder mod (e.g. for 6 hours or 1 day) also didn't work. Might this have something to do with either the UTC offset (+2 at my end) or perhaps the data source (custom data feed adapter)?

Comment: Hmm yeah I would first try converting everything to UTC, if you are on 6 hour or 1D intervals then a +2h timezone would mess it up.

Comment: To isolate the problem, I tried this in the demo page of the tradingview lib (index.html). Still the same issue as before; see https://pastebin.com/98aEv3Y2.

Comment: After drawing these shape i want to modify those shapes  or I want to clear it and redraw it programmatically, How to do that @NickFriskel